# Why is VMware vSphere Client hanging at the console?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vsphere-client

When I use the vSphere Client (against an ESXi 4.1 server) it hangs a *lot*.  It's always at the same place - using the console on a VM. The console stops responding - and a lot of times, the management window stops responding as well. The operating system won't close the window (as the application isn't responding) and requires a force close.

I've had the console refuse to give up the mouse, and have had the console freeze with the cursor in the top left (before any VM software starts, maybe?).

The environment is this: the system is a Dell laptop running Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick) fully updated with VirtualBox OSE running Windows XP (also fully updated). The vSphere Client is running in the Windows XP VM. Got all that?

How do I keep these hangs from happening? It is *very* aggravating. I'm still trying just to get the VM loaded with Ubuntu Server...

Comment: I'm still experiencing the problem with Windows XP on actual hardware. The system often locks up in the console, and requires a reboot of Windows XP in order to recover. Windows can't close any of the vSphere client windows. vSphere client is also VERY slow in connecting to hosts (whether with an authorized login or not).

Comment: There's something odd going on here, can you run the vsclient code on a Windows 7 VM on the actual host and let us know how you get on please?

Comment: Someone else in the office has been using vSphere Client with no problems on Windows 7 - using Windows 7 in an Ubuntu-hosted VM (VMware for Linux in this case) with no problems. At this point, I suspect a shortage of memory and incompatibility  with Windowx XP.

Comment: I've used well-patched XP with VSClient before successfully, though I've also seen memory leaks too.

Comment: The Windows XP host has 512M.

Comment: Things seem to be much more stable since I went back the basic XP theme instead of the sophisticated theme that was being used before (which necessitated using a DLL). Things seem quicker and I don't see the console crashes as much. At this point I consider the fancy theming to be at fault.

Comment: ha, wow, wouldn't have thought of that ever! well done.

Comment: Things have gotten much more stable now that I've moved to a machine with more memory; 512M was not enough.

Comment: I gave my vm 1gb ram and used the basic 2000 style theme from the getgo and still had it happen to me but only on a specific vm. I believe one of the other vm's I installed was a text based install so Im not sure where the issue came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's supposed to run on bare-metal Windows, I'm not surprised it's struggling with all that going on, that said make sure you're not blocking TCP 902& 903 just to be sure.

Comment: per vmware either make a windows jumpbox or a windows vm to run the console from.  He is following their directions.

Answer (score 1):

In my case a workaround is (if you have access to Vcenter) make sure focus (left click) is placed on the Guest VM you have opened in your frozen console, now when you select the console Window you will not get dinged from your PC (bell of freeze).

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same thing on my system.  I have nix host and a xp guest to get the client to run.  I tried to run  a centos install and as soon as I added the centos iso to the vm that would happen.  I was quite perplexed by it. kill the console open it again and remove the iso from the cd listing on that vm and works again.  recreated a new vm and used several different 6.x iso's same thing every time for the text install.  Since I have a linux client no proper console was built by vmware.  I found a nice little tip that allows you to use vmware player to open the console to the vm on the esxi server.  I then was able to enable and set the centos iso so it could install.

-h is the esx host address -u is the esx user   then add the proper datastore location for the vm files. 
vmplayer -h 10.1.1.1 -u "root" "[datastore1] test/test.vmx"

Answer (score -1):

In my case, Norton Protection Center, its firewall block the console